# How do I change the HTML within a DIV by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Example:

```
    for (i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
        alert(i + "," + wanted);
        $("#hint-" + $i).html("Verified as " + $i + ".<br />");
    }
```

Changes this:

```
<div id="verify-1"> </div>
<input type="radio" name="b_answer_1" id="radio-1" value="Lamb">Lamb</input><br />
<div id="verify-2"> </div>
<input type="radio" name="b_answer_2" id="radio-2" value="Llama">Llama</input><br />
<div id="verify-3"> </div>
<input type="radio" name="b_answer_3" id="radio-3" value="Goat">Goat</input><br />
```

To this:

```
                    <div id="verify-1">Verified as 1<br /></div>
<input type="radio" name="b_answer_1" id="radio-1" value="Lamb">Lamb</input><br />
                    <div id="verify-2">Verified as 2<br /></div>
<input type="radio" name="b_answer_2" id="radio-2" value="Llama">Llama</input><br />
                    <div id="verify-3">Verified as 3<br /></div>
<input type="radio" name="b_answer_3" id="radio-3" value="Goat">Goat</input><br />
```

Comment: You start by using either `$i` or `i`, not both as they are not the same thing.

Comment: You're targeting them with `$("#hint-" + $i)` but their `id`s start with "verify-"...

Comment: Next, you validate the HTML, as input elements are self closing.

Answer (score 3):

remove that `$` before `i`

```
for (i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
        alert(i + "," + wanted);
        $("#verify-" + i).html("Verified as " + i + ".<br />");
}
```

Or you can do this -

```
$("div[id^='verify-']").each(function(){
    var num = this.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[1];
    $(this).html("Verified as " + num + ".<br />");
});
```

Comment: Your second example wouldn't work if the `id` had more than one digit. You might want to use `this.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[1]` to get the number on the end

Comment: @Ian .. Thanks.. I don't know much about `regex` but i updated my answer.

Comment: No problem, just wanted you to have a reliable way to get the number at the end of the `id` :)

Answer (score 2):

Your ids are  `verify-1 , verify-2`...etc

```
for (i=1; i <= 3; i++) 
    $("#verify-" + i).html("Verified as " + i + ".<br />");
```